# How to use "Hosted inference API" of Hugging Face?

Tags: huggingface

I recently found out about the Hosted Inference API that one can put into their model repository. I love the idea of being able to run a quick demo so I was trying to implement it in [my own model repo](https://huggingface.co/jiew/mymnist/tree/main), hopping it will work like this:
[Expected example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRMZy.png).

But I don’t know how to do it, can you help me?

[Here is the files in my repo:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBbWH.png)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: No external links. All relevant code must be in the question. Please take the [tour] and read [ask] and post a [mcve]